# Why did Jobi Tupaki say "Duck" in this scene?

Tags: everything-everywhere-all-at-once

In a room, people are kneeling in a line as Deirdre speaks:

> Deirdre: Citizens of the 4,655th Thetaverse, you are about to be
> graced by the presence of our sovereign leader, Jobu Tupaki. Now let
> me assure you of one thing. Just like the rest of your miserable
> lives, this is nothing more than a statistical inevitability.

Then Jobu Tupaki walks down the line, pointing at the top of each person's head and
saying '**duck**'.

Why did Jobi Tupaki say "Duck" in this scene?

Comment: Sounds like a reference to [duck, duck, goose](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck,_duck,_goose). I saw the film but don’t remember it well enough to be sure.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a psychopathic game of ['Duck, duck, goose'](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck,_duck,_goose). In this case the Goose's goose is cooked.

"Bagel" Dierdre and Jobu Topaki's other agents have taken control of the IRS office in the "burner" universe, where "viewpoint" Evelyn was sent when she followed the instructions Alpha Waymond gave her.

In the children's game "Duck, Duck, Goose", most of the players are sitting in a circle, but one of the players, the "picker" has to point at (or tap on the head of) several other players, saying "duck" to most of them, but eventually labels one of the players a "goose". As soon as the "goose is identified,  a chase ensues. There are a couple of variations, but sometimes the "goose" has to chase down the picker otherwise, they become the next picker.

In this case, the "goose" is "burner universe" Evelyn, and Jobu kills her, with "viewpoint" Evelyn's consciousness sliding back to her own universe.

The point is to show how insanely psychopathic Jobu is, to randomly* select someone to murder the very first time we see her.

---

*not exactly randomly, as Jobu is seeking out Evelyns to kill, but having seen David Weil's revenge fantasy *[Hunters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hunters_(2020_TV_series))*, it was clear to me this was the Daniels' character exposition for Jobu.